# Reverse the hierarchy order in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hierarchy

I have to create a data frame which would contain the hierarchy of employees. The first 3 columns "Name", "Position", "Age" should stay as is, but the other columns should be reversed according to the hierarchy.

In the input, Raj is reporting to "Pos1" which is reporting "Pos2" and "Pos3" and so on. We can have positions up to "Pos30". If an employee has just 2 levels of hierarchy, there are null values in the subsequent columns.

For the output, we need to reverse the hierarchy: the value of Pos3 should come in Pos1 and same for its respective columns.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex, but efficient approach for your **30** sets of columns:

- Spark 3.1+

  ```py
  cols = ['Pos', 'Brid', 'Emid']
  groups = [F.array(df.colRegex(fr"`({'|'.join(cols)}){i}$`")) for i in range(30, 0, -1)]
  filtered = F.filter(F.array(*groups), lambda x: F.exists(x, lambda y: ~(F.isnull(y) | (y == F.lit("")))))
  df = df.select(
      "Name", "Position", "Age",
      *[filtered[x][i].alias(f"{c}{x+1}") for x in range(30) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      F.size(filtered).alias("Hierarchy_level")
  )
  ```
- Spark 2.4+

  ```py
  cols = ['Pos', 'Brid', 'Emid']
  groups = [F.array(df.colRegex(fr"`({'|'.join(cols)}){i}$`")) for i in range(30, 0, -1)]
  df = df.withColumn('_temp', F.array(*groups))
  filtered = F.expr("filter(_temp, x -> exists(x, y -> !(isnull(y) or (y = ''))))")
  df = df.select(
      "Name", "Position", "Age",
      *[filtered[x][i].alias(f"{c}{x+1}") for x in range(30) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      F.size(filtered).alias("Hierarchy_level")
  )
  ```

---

Testing with only **3** sets of columns.

Input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("Raj", "Trainee", 30, "Associate", "G104", "100675284", "Consultant", "G105", "10078696", "Sr Consultant", "G106", "1837839"),
     ("Ken", "Associate", 31, "Consultant", "G105", "10078696", "Sr Consultant", "G106", "1837839", "", None, None)],
    ["Name", "Position", "Age", "Pos1", "Brid1", "Emid1", "Pos2", "Brid2", "Emid2", "Pos3", "Brid3", "Emid3"])
df.show()
# +----+---------+---+----------+-----+---------+-------------+-----+--------+-------------+-----+-------+
# |Name| Position|Age|      Pos1|Brid1|    Emid1|         Pos2|Brid2|   Emid2|         Pos3|Brid3|  Emid3|
# +----+---------+---+----------+-----+---------+-------------+-----+--------+-------------+-----+-------+
# | Raj|  Trainee| 30| Associate| G104|100675284|   Consultant| G105|10078696|Sr Consultant| G106|1837839|
# | Ken|Associate| 31|Consultant| G105| 10078696|Sr Consultant| G106| 1837839|             | null|   null|
# +----+---------+---+----------+-----+---------+-------------+-----+--------+-------------+-----+-------+
```

Script and results:

- Spark 3.1+

  ```py
  cols = ['Pos', 'Brid', 'Emid']
  groups = [F.array(df.colRegex(fr"`({'|'.join(cols)}){i}$`")) for i in range(3, 0, -1)]
  filtered = F.filter(F.array(*groups), lambda x: F.exists(x, lambda y: ~(F.isnull(y) | (y == F.lit("")))))
  df = df.select(
      "Name", "Position", "Age",
      *[filtered[x][i].alias(f"{c}{x+1}") for x in range(3) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      F.size(filtered).alias("Hierarchy_level")
  )
  df.show()
  # +----+---------+---+-------------+-----+-------+----------+-----+--------+---------+-----+---------+---------------+
  # |Name| Position|Age|         Pos1|Brid1|  Emid1|      Pos2|Brid2|   Emid2|     Pos3|Brid3|    Emid3|Hierarchy_level|
  # +----+---------+---+-------------+-----+-------+----------+-----+--------+---------+-----+---------+---------------+
  # | Raj|  Trainee| 30|Sr Consultant| G106|1837839|Consultant| G105|10078696|Associate| G104|100675284|              3|
  # | Ken|Associate| 31|Sr Consultant| G106|1837839|Consultant| G105|10078696|     null| null|     null|              2|
  # +----+---------+---+-------------+-----+-------+----------+-----+--------+---------+-----+---------+---------------+
  ```
- Spark 2.4+

  ```py
  cols = ['Pos', 'Brid', 'Emid']
  groups = [F.array(df.colRegex(fr"`({'|'.join(cols)}){i}$`")) for i in range(3, 0, -1)]
  df = df.withColumn('_temp', F.array(*groups))
  filtered = F.expr("filter(_temp, x -> exists(x, y -> !(isnull(y) or (y = ''))))")
  df = df.select(
      "Name", "Position", "Age",
      *[filtered[x][i].alias(f"{c}{x+1}") for x in range(3) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      F.size(filtered).alias("Hierarchy_level")
  )
  ```

Proof of efficiency:

```py
df.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# Project [Name#3697, Position#3698, Age#3699L, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3780, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3790) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3790 = )), lambda x_30#3790, false)), lambda x_29#3780, false))[0][0] AS Pos1#3770, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3781, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3791) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3791 = )), lambda x_30#3791, false)), lambda x_29#3781, false))[0][1] AS Brid1#3771, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3782, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3792) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3792 = )), lambda x_30#3792, false)), lambda x_29#3782, false))[0][2] AS Emid1#3772, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3783, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3793) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3793 = )), lambda x_30#3793, false)), lambda x_29#3783, false))[1][0] AS Pos2#3773, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3784, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3794) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3794 = )), lambda x_30#3794, false)), lambda x_29#3784, false))[1][1] AS Brid2#3774, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3785, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3795) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3795 = )), lambda x_30#3795, false)), lambda x_29#3785, false))[1][2] AS Emid2#3775, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3786, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3796) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3796 = )), lambda x_30#3796, false)), lambda x_29#3786, false))[2][0] AS Pos3#3776, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3787, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3797) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3797 = )), lambda x_30#3797, false)), lambda x_29#3787, false))[2][1] AS Brid3#3777, filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3788, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3798) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3798 = )), lambda x_30#3798, false)), lambda x_29#3788, false))[2][2] AS Emid3#3778, size(filter(array(array(Pos3#3706, Brid3#3707, Emid3#3708), array(Pos2#3703, Brid2#3704, Emid2#3705), array(Pos1#3700, Brid1#3701, Emid1#3702)), lambdafunction(exists(lambda x_29#3789, lambdafunction((isnotnull(lambda x_30#3799) AND NOT (lambda x_30#3799 = )), lambda x_30#3799, false)), lambda x_29#3789, false)), true) AS Hierarchy_level#3779]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[Name#3697,Position#3698,Age#3699L,Pos1#3700,Brid1#3701,Emid1#3702,Pos2#3703,Brid2#3704,Emid2#3705,Pos3#3706,Brid3#3707,Emid3#3708]
```

Comment: Please carefully analyze the code and learn from it. If you have other questions, please create separate questions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help , I will try to analyze each bit of it and reach out to you in case of any doubts :)